# Allocating memory to a two dimensional char array, error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’

Tags: c++, pointers

Error:

```
x.cpp:641:39: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’
x.cpp:644:39: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’
```

Code:

```
int argc;
char **argv;

char **argvv;
argvv = malloc (argc * sizeof(char *));
for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
     argvv[i] = malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
}
```

*argc* and *argv* receive the arguments from the command line through main ().

Comment: Why don't you use `calloc(x, y)` instead of `malloc(x * y)`?

Comment: @ThiefMaster I will, next time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is valid C, but invalid C++.

Make sure you use a C compiler, and name your files `.c` rather than `.cpp` (GCC will infer language from file extensions in some cases).

Or write C++, and use `std::vector` (or some other container type best suited to your needs) and `std::string` to remove the memory allocation trickyness.

Comment: No – write C++, and use proper constructs.

Comment: How did you know that I am using a c++ complier? :) That cast worked! Do you know why this doesn't work on c++ directly?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Your file is called `x.cpp` according to the error log. Don't put casts if you intend to write C. And as Konrad pointed out, there are _much_ better alternatives in C++ than handling C-type strings. Use them if you're writing C++.

Comment: Mat and @IulianŞerbănoiu : WHY does c++ reject this? Any special reasons?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: yes - C++ does not allow implicit conversion from `void*` to other pointer types. C does.

Comment: Oh, so malloc returns a void* ?

Comment: Oh no :) :) I didn't, but I will.

Answer (score 2):

```
int argc;
char **argv;

char **argvv;
argvv = new char*[argc];
for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
     argvv[i] = new char[200];
}
```

Use C++'s `new` and `delete` operators.

**LATER EDIT:**

Also the deletion (equivalent of `free` in C):

```
for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
     delete [] argvv[i]; // mind the [] for array destruction
}

delete argvv;
```

Answer (score -2):

`malloc` returns a `void*`.  You need to cast them to the correct type e.g. `argvv = (char**)malloc(....`.

Comment: That is not necessary, nor advised, in C.